# How do I test variables in a Angular JS factory using Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocking, jasmine, bdd

I want to test the `questionsBucket` in this facotry

```
.factory('QA', function(ShuffleArray, RandWords){
        var answersBucket = RandWords.get(9);
        var questionsBucket = answersBucket;
        var questionToRemove, answers, question;

        var QA = {
            answers: function(amount){
                if(typeof(amount) === 'undefined') amount = 3;

                answers = ShuffleArray.shuffle(answersBucket).slice(0,amount);
                return answers;
              },
            question: function(){
                questionToRemove = questionsBucket.indexOf(answers[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]);
                question = questionsBucket.splice(questionToRemove, 1)[0];
                return question;
              }
          };
        return QA;
      });
```

As you can see the `questionsBucket` is a variable which is not returned in the QA object, I do not want to it be exposed to anything using it.

In Ruby there are a number of ways to get this data or access private methods, but I can't see how to do it in Angular.

Here is how I'd like to write my test in Jasmine.

```
  it('should remove a question from the questionsBucket',
  inject(function(QA){
    var answers = QA.answers(5);
    var question = Qa.question();

    //I can't access the questionBucket :(
    expect(QA.questionsBucket).toEqual(4);

  }));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to test it in your factory, return it or return a function to get it.

```
.factory('QA', function(ShuffleArray, RandWords){
    var answersBucket = RandWords.get(9);
    var questionsBucket = answersBucket;
    var questionToRemove, answers, question;

    var QA = {
        //return it-->
        questionsBucket: questionsBucket,
        //return a way to get it-->
        getQuestionsBucket: function(){
            return questionsBucket;
        },
        answers: function(amount){
            if(typeof(amount) === 'undefined') amount = 3;

            answers = ShuffleArray.shuffle(answersBucket).slice(0,amount);
            return answers;
          },
        question: function(){
            questionToRemove = questionsBucket.indexOf(answers[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]);
            question = questionsBucket.splice(questionToRemove, 1)[0];
            return question;
          }
      };
    return QA;
  });
```

An alternative option would be to use a service instead and return questionsBucket as a member of the service:

```
.service('QA', function(ShuffleArray, RandWords){
    var answersBucket = RandWords.get(9);
    this.questionsBucket = answersBucket;
    var questionToRemove, answers, question;

    this.answers= function(amount){
        if(typeof(amount) === 'undefined') amount = 3;

        answers = ShuffleArray.shuffle(answersBucket).slice(0,amount);
        return answers;
    };
    this.question= function(){
        questionToRemove = questionsBucket.indexOf(answers[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]);
        question = questionsBucket.splice(questionToRemove, 1)[0];
        return question;
     };
  });
```

Or - you could create another service/provider/factory and inject that into your QA service/factory:

```
app.service('Buckets', function(RandWords){
  this.answers = RandWords.get(9);
  this.questions = answersBucket;
});
app.service('QA', function(ShuffleArray, Buckets){
  this.answersBucket = Buckets.answers;
  this.questionsBucket = Buckets.questions;
  /*all the rest here - omitted for brevity*/
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I have implemented the first way, however I really do not want the questionBucket to be accessible in normal code. I a just wonder if there is a way to set it as a private variable but they make the test access it?

Comment: Nope. Without a closure or a handle to it, you can't do it; however, in your case, you may find benefit in moving the `questionsBucket` and `answersBucket` into their own service/provider/factory and injecting it anywhere you need it. Then you can isolate and test that injectable properly as its own thing.